# Expect script, help handling multiple options in order, and only once

Tags: tcl, expect

```
expect {
    "Error: 1*#" {
        send_user "\nSpecific Error\n"
    }
    "Error: *#" {
        send_user "\nError Happened\n"
    }
    "*#" {
        send_user "\nNo Error\n"
    }
}
```

Basically what I'm looking to happen is

1. Check for text "Error: 1", anything between and then the "#" prompt.

If found, send first message to the user

2. If that's not found check for "Error:" anything at all, and then the "#" prompt.

If found, send an error message to the user

3. If none of that is met, check for just the "#" prompt

If found, send a message to the user.

I can't reliably get it to work in that order and ONLY do one of those.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the regular expression pattern `.*#` and upon matching you can look for the desired words.

```
expect -re ".*#"
set match $expect_out(0,string)
if {[string first "Error: 1" $match]!=-1} {
    # scenario 1
} elseif {[string first "Error:" $match]!=-1} {
    # scenario 2
} else {
    # scenario 3
}
```

If you really want all-in-one regular expression to match, instead of checking it using `if` condition, then you can use the following pattern,

```
(Error:)?\s*(1)?.*#
```

You have to check whether `expect_out(1,string)` and `expect_out(2,string)` exists or not. This is to ensure it contains the desired word.

Comment: That looks like it could work for what I'm doing.  I'll give it a try tomorrow when I have access to the script.